# small named shared-counter

Tags: winapi, synchronization, shared-memory

I am looking at Windows synchronization objects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411(v=VS.85).aspx, those that can be opened as named objects.

Which objects can hold small amount (4-8 bytes) of shared info that san be Set by one process and Read by another process ? I realize shared memory does this, but it can be overkill with 4kb size pages and APIs that are longer than small APIs of synchronization objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most efficient method would be to use a message. It is rather ugly, however, as you must have a message pump. You can send a `WM_USER` or a registered message type to another thread via [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to a window or [PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to  a thread.

Answer (score 1):

Using hidden windows, you can use [SetProp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633568%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetProp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633564%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions